# How to zoom into element of svg using reveal.js?

Tags: svg, zooming, markdown, reveal.js

I'm including svg images into a reveal.js presentation using markdown:

```
![alt-name](resource/foo.svg)
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to zoom into an element of the svg image, e.g. an embedded textbox using zoom.js.

Here's the relevant HTML which includes the above markdown:

```
<section data-markdown="myfile.md"
         data-separator="^\n\n\n"
         data-separator-vertical="^\n\n"
         data-separator-notes="^Note:">
</section>

<script>
  Reveal.initialize({
    zoomKey: 'ctrl',
    dependencies: [
      { src: 'plugin/zoom-js/zoom.js', async: true }
    ]
  });
</script>
```

So click-zooming on the SVG element just zooms the whole canvas, and I'd like to zoom into individual elements of the SVG.

Comment: What have you tried? Could you provide an example of your non-working code?

Comment: I edited my initial question in order to answer